# md5sum check fails - typo in filename?

Tags: boot, 20.04, iso

When booting into ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso it starts to check the disk for errors and says that 3 files are missing.
Iso file is sha-validated.
When browsing the iso from both 7-zip on Windows 10 and Windows explorer, I've found files similar to missing ones, except their file names were truncated.
Full file name is less than 120 symbols.
It that a typo or Windows/7-zip problem?
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYloF.png)

Comment: Which tool did you use to create the boot drive? And what kind of drive is it (DVD or USB pendrive or memory card)? Or did you boot directly from the iso file via grub or a virtual machine?

Comment: I've created an empty fat32 partition on my SSD from Windows 10 (tried both diskpart and Disk Management), extracted everything from iso to that partition (tried both 7zip and Windows Explorer) and added line to my rEFInd config to boot /EFI/boot/grubx64.efi from that partition. "Try Ubuntu" works btw, but installing fails with "cannot unmount /cdrom". When umounting /cdrom manually, installer then gets stuck at "scanning filesystems" or something

Comment: Are you trying to install Ubuntu into the same drive as you are booting from? I think the installer has a protection from that (you cannot umount /cdrom). If that is really what you want, you have to boot Ubuntu to RAM with the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `toram`.

Comment: I don't know if the extracting tools in Windows will modify the file names. But you can install the tool Rufus, and let it create a USB boot drive with Ubuntu. This is by far the easiest way to boot Ubuntu live and to install Ubuntu. If you already have Ubuntu or some other similar linux distro, there are several tools/methods to create USB boot drives.

Comment: Thanks! These 3 files were still missing, but with `toram` installation succeeded anyway.

Comment: Congratulations, and thanks for letting us know what happened :-)